# How to send a message to a particular content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am try to send a activate message to two different content scripts (script1, script2), but when i send message to script2, script1 activates.

```
    // Function to activate script1

    function script1(id, type, icon) {
        console.log("inside inspect");
        this.id = id;
        window.browser.tabs.executeScript(id, {
       file: script1File
       }, function () { window.browser.tabs.sendMessage(id, { action: 
       type }); }.bind(this));
     }


    //Function to activate script2

     function script2(id, type, icon) {
        console.log("inside inspect");
        this.id = id;
        window.browser.tabs.executeScript(id, {
        file: script2File
        }, function () { window.browser.tabs.sendMessage(id, { action: 
        type }); }.bind(this));
      }
```

Whenever I call script1, it works perfectly but in case where I execute script2, then also script1 executes.

Comment: Messaging API can't target a specific script. It can only target a specific tab id or frameId. You can simply add an additional parameter in your message or add something to `type` like `type + '1'` and `type + '2'` and of course edit the content scripts to check the corresponding action.

Comment: Great thanks for the help buddy